# Why does the compiler not always optimize away local variables?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, micro-optimization

I am trying to understand if the removal of local intermediate variables could lead to better optimized code. Consider the following MWE, paying particular attention to the two functions `f` and `g`:

```
struct A {
    double d;
};

struct B {
    double s;
};

struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
};

A geta();
B getb();

C f() {
    const A a = geta();
    const B b = getb();

    C c;
    c.a = a;
    c.b = b;
    return c;
}

C g() {
    C c;
    c.a = geta();
    c.b = getb();
    return c;
}
```

Both `f` and `g` call `geta()` and `getb()` to populate an instance of class `C` which is then returned, but `f` uses two local intermediate variables to store the returned values of `geta()` and `getb()`, while `g` directly assigns the returned values to the members of `c`.

Compiling with `gcc -O3`, version 9.2, the binaries for the two functions `f` and `g` are exactly the same. However, adding another variable to either `A` or `B` class leads to **different** binaries. In particular, the binary for `f` has some more instructions. The same holds for clang v8.0.0 with `-O3` flag.

What is happening here? Why is the compiler not able to optimize away the local intermediate variables of `f` when `A` or `B` get a little more complex? Isn't the code of `f` and `g` equivalent?

---

In addition, the behavior is not the same for MSVC v19.22 with `/O2` flag: the compiler from Microsoft already has different binaries in the first case, i.e. with both classes `A` and `B` composed by a single `double`.

I am using Godbolt: you can find [here](https://godbolt.org/z/AXNaPb) the code which produces different binaries.

Comment: The compiler doesn't optimize away locals in a willly-nilly manner. The compiler is only free to optimize out those variable that produce no *Side-Effects* within your code. `A` and `B` call functions, `C` (`c`) assign to members and return values. It's hard given your snippet to identify what you think should be optimized out? Further variables selected to take out are single variables. If you have an object and several member of that object (say `.a` and `.b` do nothing), they still are unlikely to be optimized away as they are not independent variables.

Comment: If you provide a simple definition for `getA()` and `getB()`, the asm is the same for `f()` and `g()`. https://godbolt.org/z/lOjAC-

Comment: @Sebi so one could ask: what could be inside `getA()` and `getB()` that prevents optimization? Equivalently: how simple should `getA()` and `getB()` be to allow optimization?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the functions would be called either way so no side-effects are harmed. GCC optimized the first version (without the `int` in `struct A`) so evidently it is possible at least sometimes (or GCC is wrong, which does happen)

Comment: If you add trivial custom assignment operator to `A`, it will in `gcc` make `f()` and `g()` machine code identical again... :D :D :D ... (the code to add inside `struct A`: `A & operator = (const A &t) { return *this; }` .... seems like default assignment operator is either doing something "extra" which prevents the collapsing, or the mere fact the operator is not explicit and gcc has to fill the gap with default one prevents the optimizer to collapse it. .... But general answer to your question is actually super simple: "why not?" ... it's optimizer, not "find optimal solution-izer".

Comment: Unless you want to know precise logic used to achieve that machine code, then you have to consult the gcc sources, how the compiler and optimizer are implemented. If you will try it, maybe you will realize how much stuff is actually there and how things seemingly trivial to human may turn out to be lot more complex than expected in the implementation... and in the end the compiler should finish compilation is some reasonable finite time, while the amount of possible machine code variants to implement even simple source in question are in hundred thousands or more, only fraction is considered..

Comment: (although this feels like something reasonable to report to gcc team as missed optimization, or maybe they will explain why it works like this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is a missed optimization**

Neither function takes the address of `C c` so escape analysis should easily prove it's a pure local that nothing else could have a pointer to.  `geta()` and `getb()` can't be reading or writing that variable directly, therefore it's safe to store the `geta()` return value directly into `c.a` instead of a temporary on the stack.

Surprisingly GCC, clang, ICC, and MSVC all miss this optimization, most using call-preserved registers to hold the `geta()` return value until after `getb()`.  https://godbolt.org/z/WQ9MAF  At least for x86-64; I mostly didn't check other ISAs or older compiler versions.

Fun fact: clang 3.5 has this missed-optimization even for `g()`, defeating the source code's attempt to be efficient.

Fun fact #2: With GCC9.2, compiling as C instead of C++ makes GCC do a much worse job, deoptimizing `g()`.  (I had to change to `typedef struct Atag {...} A;` but compiling that as C++ still optimizes `g()`.  https://godbolt.org/z/_Y95nj)

clang8.0 produces an efficient `g()` with/without `-xc`. and ICC produces an inefficient `g()` either way.

ICC's `f()` is even worse than its `g()`.

---

MSVC's `g()` is about efficient as you could hope for; the Windows x64 calling convention returns the struct by hidden pointer and MSVC never optimizes that to passing a pointer to its own return-value object.  (Which it probably couldn't prove is safe anyway, if its own caller was also potentially doing such optimizations.)

---

Obviously if `geta()` and `getb()` can inline, that removes any doubt for the optimizer and it should do the optimization more easily / reliably.